# Android Back Button and Progress Dialog

Tags: android, button, dialog, progress, back

I have an *AsyncTask* that shows a progressDialog whilst working (it calls *runOnUiThread* from within *doInBackground* to show the progress dialog).

Whilst its running I want to allow the use of the back button to cancel the operation; someone else has had this problem: [BACK Button is not working ,while progressDialog is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919676/back-button-is-not-working-while-progressdialog-is-running)

For what ever reason I can't reply to that thread, hence having to start another?! (Another question for another day)

I had the same idea as Sandy but this code is never called whilst the *progressDialog* is showing, why is this? I have implemented it inside my main activity class, does the *progressDialog* take the foreground focus away from my class temporarily?

Comment: Hmm, I see I can over ride onBackPressed but again, this is only called when the progressDialog isn't running? If I set my progressDialog to cancelable perhaps I can override an 'onCancel' method if it has one?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

First, you should show your dialog from `OnPreExecute`, hide it in `OnPostExecute`, and - if necessary - modify it by publishing progress. (see [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html))

Now to your question: `ProgressDialog.show()` can take a `OnCancelListener` as an argument. You should provide one that calls `cancel()` on the progress dialog instance.

example:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        _progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                YourActivity.this,
                "Title",
                "Message",
                true,
                true,
                new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        YourTask.this.cancel(true);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

where `_progressDialog` is a `ProgressDialog` member of `YourTask`.

> This class was deprecated in API level 26. ProgressDialog is a modal
>   dialog, which prevents the user from interacting with the app. Instead
>   of using this class, you should use a progress indicator like
>   ProgressBar, which can be embedded in your app's UI. Alternatively,
>   you can use a notification to inform the user of the task's progress. [LINK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog)

Comment: This is what I found. I conducted more research my self, together with your answer given, I have made it work using your suggestion :)

Answer (score 17):

This can be achieved by the following code fragment:

```
progress.setCancelable(true);
progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

progress is the ProgressDialog object...

This will enable the back button to close the dialog but prevent any touch input to do that...

Answer (score 14):

Well, I had the same issue. The simplest method that worked for me is using `progressDialog.setCancelable(true)`.. This declares whether the dialog is cancelable by hitting the back key.. Try it and let me know if it works for you or not. Good luck

Comment: Hi Farhan, as per user634618's suggestions I used an onCancelListener() :D

Answer (score 10):

I just found a perfect and simplest solution to this problem. There's a method in `ProgressDialog` to set KeyListener.

```
progressDialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && !event.isCanceled()) {
            if(progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                //your logic here for back button pressed event
            } 
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

It's working fine with `setCancelable(false)`. I am also checking for `event.isCanceled()`, because without that I was getting two events. I've tested this on Lollipop device with and without Hardware keys.

Answer (score 5):

Treating back button like a cancellation is not the correct way.
Cancellation also occurs when a user touches the screen outside of the dialog box.
You want to differentiate those two actions, no?

Correct approach would be to extend the ProgressDialog class and override the onBackPressed method.

```
private class SubProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {
    public SubProgressDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        /** dismiss the progress bar and clean up here **/
    }
}


public void displayProgressBar(){
    progressBar = new SubProgressDialog(this);
    progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressBar.setCancelable(false);
    progressBar.setMessage(getString(R.string.authorizing));        
    progressBar.show();   
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
      }
       }).start();
```

}

Notice the setCancelable(false), again emphasizing that back button is different than a simple cancellation.
Also this will effecitvely ignore any other touch inputs from the user.

Comment: No need to subclass ProgressDialog, Implement onCancelListener and use progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); for getting same effect.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution to this. The PD problem occurs only when the app exiting on back button (Usually when the user presses it repetitively, and only sometimes (not all the times) the PD is called when the app already destroyed. Dismissing the PD `onDestroy` doesn't work for some reason and when I've tried it, each Back button press would close the app although `canGoBack()` was set to true. Instead I dismiss the PD on `goBack` which is the event that causes the collision in the first place, and I do it right before `finish()`. If the app exits on goBack normally there's no problem in the first place.

BTW, 'difference' is aimed to let the user to exit the app with a fast double click (400 MS between two clicks) instead of going back from page to page.

Hope it helps someone...

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            difference = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            if (wView.canGoBack() && difference > 400) {
                wView.goBack();
            } else {
                dismissProgressDialog();
                finish();
            }
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


private void dismissProgressDialog() {
   if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

javano... I tested your scenario using standard techniques, asyncTask and ProgressDialog. In my test, when the progressDialog is showing and i hit back, the progressdialog is dismissed and the background thread continues to run. I do not know why you need to call runOnUiThread.

SO:

show the progressDialog in onPreExecute
place the long running task in doInBackground
dismiss the progressDialog in onPostExecute
pass the input parameters to your long running task as in:

```
new MyAsynch().execute(password,inString);
```

cancel() the asynchTask and progressDialog in onPause

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (asynch != null) {asynch.cancel(true);}
    if (progress != null){progress.cancel();}
}
```

JAL

I have some code [here](http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/asynch).

Comment: Yep, this is pretty much what I was after. Managed to get it working with a interruptible progress dialogue :)

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple just copy the below code and paste within Async task..

ProgressDialog dialog;

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this) {
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            dialog.cancel();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    };
    // dialog.setTitle("file is..");//its optional If u want set title in progress
    // bar
    dialog.setMessage("Loading file....");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    dialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this, it shows the cancel button only async and finish will call by clicking on cancel button

```
protected void onPreExecute() {


        dialogx.setMessage("Loading... Please Wait...");
        dialogx.setCancelable(false);
        dialogx.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,
                "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialogx.dismiss();
                GetDataTask.this.cancel(true);
                finish();
            }
        });
        dialogx.show();


    }
```