# Android Back button doesn't work with dialog

Tags: java, android

Pretty simple; The dialog is showing. I press the back button on the phone, nothing happens. I've tried this, but it never gets called:

```
static void ProgressDialog(Context context)
{
    String text = context.getString(R.string.dialog_loading_video);
    vDialog = new ProgressDialog(context)
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
            {

                // Nothing happening here!

            }

            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    };

    vDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", text);
    vDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Back Button and Progress Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253621/android-back-button-and-progress-dialog)

Comment: You realize that you are redefining `vDialog` right after you assign to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get rid of the second assignment to `vDialog`. Then, you need to make your dialog cancelable by calling `setCancelable(boolean)`.

Comment: So that makes the back button remove the dialog, but I need to move to the last activity. How do I set onBackButton on this code:
lDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", text);
lDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
lDialog.setCancelable(true);

Comment: So this works... but the problem is the back button dismisses it, then I have to press back again to get to the previous screen...this is what I want: If the dialog is showing when I press back, it goes to the onKeyDown override in my current activity, then from there I dismiss the dialog manually.  How do I do this?

Comment: You can set an OnDismissListener for the dialog that will be informed when the dialog goes away. From that you can call finish() for the activity.

Comment: Ted, thanks. My problem is my dialogs are in a static non-activity class...to show the dialog, from the activity I pass in the context that the dialog should be shown on.  How do I get my activity to listen for onDismissListener? Because obviously this wont work:  lDialog.setOnDismissListener(context);

Comment: Alright I got it. I used OnCancelListener(because I need to know when its cancelled on not dismissed). Then in my activity I create my onCancelListener and then I pass that into the static dialog class.  A lot of work for something seemingly simple.  Thanks

Comment: I agree--a lot of work for something simple. You could make the activity class implement OnCancelListener and register itself when it creates the dialog. That avoids a separate little class at the expense of violating some OO design principle the name of which I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

In line `vDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", text);` you create new Dialog that doesn't have overriden `onKeyDown()` method. Replace this line with these code:

```
vDialog.setTitle("");
vDialog.setMessage(text);
vDoalog.show();
```